# How to add ssl certificate pinning in ios app swift4 using alamofire manager?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl-certificate, alamofire, certificate-pinning

I have problem on ssl certificate pinning in my ios app, what I want is add ssl pinning certificate to all requests using alamofire, so below is my code of the alamofire manager, when I run the app I always get this error:

> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999
>   "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myWebsite.com/token,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myWebsite.com/token,
>   _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask .<1>" ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]

```
class AFManager : NSObject{

private var sessionManager: SessionManager?


required override init() {
    super.init()

    enableCertificatePinning()

}

private func enableCertificatePinning() {
    let certificates = getCertificates()
    let trustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
        certificates: certificates,
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        validateHost: true)
    let trustPolicies = [ "myWebsite.com": trustPolicy ]
    let policyManager =  ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: trustPolicies)
    sessionManager = SessionManager(
        configuration: .default,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: policyManager)
}

private func getCertificates() -> [SecCertificate] {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myWebsitessl", withExtension: "cer")!
    let localCertificate = try! Data(contentsOf: url) as CFData
    guard let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate)
        else { return [] }

    return [certificate]
}



///without headers (post)
//used this to registration
class func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    self.init().sessionManager?.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

        //print(responseObject)

        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            success(resJson)
        }
        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}


///// response string (post)
//used this in login // used in change password
class func strRequestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : String]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    self.init().sessionManager?.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        //print(response)

        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(response.result.value!)
            success(resJson)
        }
        if response.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = response.result.error!

            failure(error)
        }

    }

  }

}
```

My code was like this, see code below, and it was working, but I want certificate pinning for security so I add the things(Like sessionManager, init(),enableCertificatePinning() and getCertificates()) in the above code and after that its not working

```
class AFManager : NSObject{


///without headers (post)
//used this to registration
class func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

        //print(responseObject)

        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            success(resJson)
        }
        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}


///// response string (post)
//used this in login // used in change password
class func strRequestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : String]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        //print(response)

        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(response.result.value!)
            success(resJson)
        }
        if response.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = response.result.error!

            failure(error)
        }

    }

  }

}
```

I added the certificate to my project by drag and drop it inside the project, please help, I feel my code has some mistakes
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Error `-999` is most commonly seen when your `SessionManager` is `deinit`'d while being used, causing all of your requests to be cancelled. From your code its looks like you're not using the `sessionManager` variable you've created with your custom `ServerTrustPolicy` at all and even if you were it's likely that whatever instance of `AFManager` you've created is going out of scope, causing the `deinit`.

Comment: thank you for replay, I understand your saying but how I can do that with my code

Comment: Most commonly it's done using a singleton, but dependency injection can do it too, as long as the injector has a longer lifetime than your requests.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sessionManager`,  I use this class below, it creates array of certificates from your bundle;

```
class NetworkManager
{
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()
    var manager: SessionManager?

    init()
    {
        var certificates = ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(in: Bundle.main)

        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "yourUrl.com": .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(in: Bundle.main),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            )
        ]

        manager = SessionManager(
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )


    }
}
```

Then I do request like that,

```
     //request depends on your needs. Post, get etc..
        var request = URLRequest(url: yourUrl)
        request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        networkManager.manager!.request(request).responseJSON
```

By the way don't forget to create your networkManager object

```
var networkManager = NetworkManager.sharedInstance
```